# Outlook: how do I display the email address in TO:, rather than the account?

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have an exchange mailbox called "Support" with two email addresses:
foo@company.com (primary)
bar@company.com

Mail to both addresses goes to the same inbox correctly and message show as To: Support.  if I check the details of the To: field it always shows foo@company.com, even when messages were sent to bar@company.com.  Viewing the full message headers shows bar@company.com

How can I get Outlook to show the actual email address the message was sent to?  It's an issue for the people managing the mailbox because knowing what the target address was is important to determine how the message should be handled.

Comment: I think that the 'foo@company.com' address is default (created from account name), and the 'bar@company.com' is only alias so you can add rule (in outlook with option 'send to') to separate those mails to different sub-folders (for example inbox/foo and inbox/bar) by checking header. Check this out, please. I think that, the 'rules' is only good way to solve your problem.

Comment: @japao: It would still be mangling the `to` field though. So while that would work, it still wouldn't be a very good solution. Can there really be no way to keep it from mangling the fields?

Comment: Ok, if that rule is not working, please try to use rule named "with specific words in the recipient's address" and put in alias name. In my Outlook it's working.

Comment: I found this now: http://support.ravenit.com/entries/20964098-how-do-i-separate-messages-addressed-to-an-email-alias-from-messages-delivered-to-the-primary-email-

Answer (score 1):

In the end I gave up on unmangling the address; using a rule on "specific words in the recipient's address" was promising but turned out to be a client-only rule, not practical with multiple users to be co-ordinated.

What I did was create a mailbox for every address, all of them set to forward to the combined mailbox under Exchange General -> Delivery Options.  Now when outlook resolves a to: address it finds the mailbox for just that address, and then displays the default address of that mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to try is to use a distribution list (which can also have multiply aliases) which forwards the mail to the destination mailbox and will show the original to address.